# Overriding a python instance method in a external library

Tags: python, overriding, cx-oracle

I've written a context manager for a database connection.
I would like to override a method from an external class ('execute' in cx_oracle.Cursor), to drop any extraneous bind variables before passing the query to the database (or else they result in a DatabaseError).  The issue of why they would be there to begin with is orthogonal.

The following works, but I'm wondering about whether I'm using **_*getattribute*_** correctly here (haven't really had an excuse to use it before).

I'm also "all ears"...er eyes...if anyone has a better suggestion on how to over-ride this method from this external library.

Thanks.  I'm using python 2.7

```
import cx_Oracle
from contextlib import contextmanager

class Cursor(cx_Oracle.Cursor):
    """A wrapper for cx_Oracle cursors that will drop extraneous bind variables passed to in"""

    def __init__(self, curs):
        self.curs = curs

    def execute(self, sql, *args, **kwargs):
        params = {}
        print("in execute, args[0] = [%s]" % str(args[0]))
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], dict):
            for bv in args[0].keys():
                if ':%s' % bv in sql:
                    params[bv] = args[0][bv]
            print('params = %s' % str(params))
        else:
            return self.curs.execute(sql, *args, **kwargs)

        return self.curs.execute(sql, params)


    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'execute':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        elif name == 'curs':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, 'curs')
        else:
            curs = object.__getattribute__(self, 'curs')
            return cx_Oracle.Cursor.__getattribute__(curs, name)


@contextmanager
def db_conn():

    pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool("user", "pwd", "database", min=2, max=10, increment=1, threaded=True)
    conn = pool.acquire()

    try:
        yield Cursor(conn.cursor())
    except:
        conn.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        conn.commit()
    finally:
        pool.release(conn)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with db_conn() as curs:
        curs.execute('select * from dual where 1 = :a', {'a':1, 'b':2})
        print(curs.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `__getattr__` method, rather than `__getattribute__`, you don't have to special case the names in your own class. It only looks at `__getattr__` if it can't find the attribute by the normal means.

Something like:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.curs, name)
```

You'll need to change `class Cursor(cx_Oracle.Cursor):` to `class Cursor(object):`. It's tricky to do what you're trying to by subclassing, because the cursor is created by a method of the database connection. You could subclass the SessionPool as well, so that its `cursor` method returns your custom cursor instance, but it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks exactly like what I wanted (I need to get more familiar with the special methods).  The only reason I was subclassing cx_Oracle.Cursor to begin with was to get its other methods automatically.  This gives me that.

Comment: @Gerrat: You're welcome. There's plenty of info here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html